# How to convert data to such a structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, data-conversion

How to transform array `oArr` to result like the example below

example:

input:

```
let oArr = [
   {
      '1': Object,
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '2': Object,
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '1': Object,
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }, {
      '3': Objcet,
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }
]
```

output:

```
result = [
    {
      'range': [0, 778],
      '1': Object,
      '2': Object
    },  {
      'range': [779, 1500],
      '1': Object,
      '3': Object
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the rule? Do you combine by range? Would there be overlapping ranges  (e.g., `[0, 10]` and `[5, 15]`) or would they always be either the same or different?

Comment: Hello Hughie, please tell us what approach you have tried ? Are you facing issue with some syntax or methods in javascript.

Comment: yes, just combine by range, and there's no overlapping ranges, the range property is fixed before this convertion by order like [0, 100], [101, 200], [201, 300]....

Answer (score 1):

Use `reducer` function on each element of the array to group them on range value and set the other key on the result by iterating all properties except range.

```js
oArr = [
   {
      '1': 'Object',
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '2': 'Object',
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '1': 'Object',
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }, {
      '3': 'Object',
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }
];


var result = Object.values(oArr.reduce((c, obj) => {
  c[obj.range] = c[obj.range] || {'range': obj.range};
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { 
    if(key === 'range') continue;
    c[obj.range][key] = value;
  }
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let oArr = [
   {
      '1': {Object: 'object1'},
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '2': {Object: 'object2'},
      'range': [0, 778]
   }, {
      '1': {Object: 'object3'},
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }, {
      '3': {Object: 'object4'},
      'range': [779, 1500]
   }
];

let res = [];
oArr.forEach( obj => {
  let index = res.indexOf( res.find(resObj => resObj.range[0] === obj.range[0] && resObj.range[1] === obj.range[1] ));
  console.log(index);
  let key = Object.keys(obj).find(key => key != 'range');
  index === -1? res.push( obj ) : res[index][key] = obj[key];
});

console.log(res);
```

Note: this solution assumes the following:

1. There is no more than one object for each range in the source array.
2. range array has only 2 values always, and they'll be same order (e.g `range: [0,100]` and `range: [100,0]` would be consider different.